# Layout for checkbox group with prompt label

Tags: android, layout, checkbox

I'm very new in the Android app development so please don't wonder about my question.
I already studied the documentation and know which components were offered and how I can use it.
Now the problem is that I have some difficulties to find the right xml layout for my special situation:

I want to have three checkboxes, arranged in one row (the first checkbox on top, the scond one in the middle and the third one on bottom).
Then I want to place these checkboxes in a container so I can enable/disable the whole container by one call and not each checkbox separately.
And that container should also show a kind of heading which describes the selection with a short text (prompt label).

I'm glad about any idea and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you meant one column, this may work for you:

(To enable/disable the whole container, simply call `setVisibility(View.GONE)` on the linear layout named "checkbox_layout")

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/checkbox_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Header"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Label 1" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Label 2" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Label 3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That looks good for me, thanks! But can you also tell me how to set a heading for this group? I mean some text which can be found in f.e. a setting dialog to title separate sections.

Comment: I've one more question for understanding: As I noticed you're using <TextView/> to label the checkboxes. Is there a difference in defining the label with android:text for <CheckBox/> directly?

Comment: actually I just forgot that existed, that would be better